# Writing a NSPredicate to find if the date falls between a certain range

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to write a NSPredicate to see if the provided date falls between a certain time internal.

For example if i provide the data `12 Mar, 2012`. It needs to see if it falls between the `startdate` and `enddate`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(statrDate >= %@) AND (enddate <= %@)", providedDate, ProvidedDate];
```

1.) in the above example `startdate` is `10 Mar 2012`, and `endDate` is `20 Mar 2012`. But the `NSPredicate` doesn't return anything because i have specified 12 Mar 2012 as `providedDate`.

2.) Can i make use of the `BETWEEN` clause so this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Use a compound predicate:

```
NSPredicate *greaterThanPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"statrDate <= %@", providedDate];
NSPredicate *lessThanPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"enddate >= %@", providedDate];
NSPredicate *betweenPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:greaterThanPredicate, lessThanPredicate, nil]];
```

I used `>=` and `<=` because you did. If it's not supposed to be inclusive, switch to `>` and `<` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove brackets and try :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"statrDate >= %@ AND enddate <= %@", providedDate, ProvidedDate];
```